# Regular expressions, allow specific format only. "John-doe"

Tags: php, regex

I've researched a little, but I found nothing that relates exactly to what I need and whenever tried to create the expression it is always a little off from what I require.

I attempted something along the lines of `[AZaz09]{3,8}\-[AZaz09]{3,8}`.

I want the valid result to only allow text-text, where either or the text can be alphabetical or numeric however the only symbol allowed is `-` and that is in between the two texts.

Each text must be at least three characters long ({3,8}?), then separated by the `-`.

Therefore for it to be valid some examples could be:

```
Text-Text
Abc-123
123-Abc
A2C-def4gk
```

Invalid tests could be:

```
Ab-3
Abc!-ajr4
a-bc3-25aj
a?c-b%
```

Comment: Do you want accented letters or other alphabets to also match? Like "déjà-vus", "12µ-13µ", "mañana-1234"

Comment: @trincot: Good point, have updated my answer to reflect the `u` modifier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use anchors and use the `-` so the characters in the character class are read as a range, not the individual characters.

Try:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{3,8}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xH3oM8/1

You also could simplify it a but with the `i` modifier and the `\d` meta character.

```
(?i)^[a-z\d]{3,8}-[a-z\d]{3,8}$
```

Comment: Top one seems to be perfect for my use :)

Comment: I noticed that in the site there is /gm at the end of the regex, what does this gm do and is it required?

Comment: `g` is a global modifier, `m` is multi-line. That is just to demonstrate there. The `g` isn't supported in PHP. The `m` makes the `^$` match each line, rather than the whole string.

Answer (score 6):

If accented letters should be allowed, or any other letter that exists in the Unicode range (like Greek or Cyrillic letters), then use the [`u`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier (for UTF-8 support) and [`\pL`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) to match Unicode letters (and `\d` for digits):

```
$string ="
Mañana-déjà
Text-Text
Abc-123
123-Abc
A2C-def4gk
Ab-3
Abc!-ajr4
a-bc3-25aj
a?c-b%";

$regex='/^[\pL\d]{3,}-[\pL\d]{3,}$/mu';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

var_export($matches);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Mañana-déjà',
    1 => 'Text-Text',
    2 => 'Abc-123',
    3 => '123-Abc',
    4 => 'A2C-def4gk',
  ),
)
```

NB: the difference with `\w` is that `[\pL\d]` will not match an underscore.

Answer (score 5):

You could come up with the following:

```
<?php
$string ="
Text-Text
Abc-123
123-Abc
A2C-def4gk
Ab-3
Abc!-ajr4
a-bc3-25aj
a?c-b%";

$regex='~
        ^\w{3,}  # at last three word characters at the beginning of the line
        -        # a dash
        \w{3,}$  # three word characters at the end of the line
        ~xm';    # multiline and freespacing mode (for this explanation)
                 # ~xmu for accented characters

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

As @chris85 pointed out, `\w` will match an underscore as well. Trincot had a good comment (matching accented characters, that is). To achieve this, [simply use the `u` modifier](https://regex101.com/r/tE0dU6/2).
See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tE0dU6/1) and [a complete code on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/oMe3Qp).

Comment: The PHP won't work with the explanation in there, you should do that in the question's body by itself.

Comment: @chris85: [Why not???](http://ideone.com/oMe3Qp) - this is exactly what the `x` modifier is for.

Comment: @trincot never used `x` modifier but doesn't work here, https://eval.in/526650. I'll look at that modifier though.

Comment: Ah, I see now, thats a tricky modifier I hadn't encountered, can't upvote twice. Still doesn't work in that other environment though, not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex

```
^\w{3,}-\w{3,}$

^       // start of the string
\w{3,}  // match "a" to "z", "A" to "Z" and 0 to 9 and requires at least 3 characters
-       // requires "-"
\w{3,}  // same as above
$       // end of the string
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uE1vK6/1)

Answer (score 2):

And a short one.

```
^([^\W_]{3,8})-(?1)$
```

- `[^\W_]` can be used as [short for alnum](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html#obnoxious). It subtracts the underscore from `\w`
- `(?1)` is a [subroutine call](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) to the pattern in first group

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gB1mI9/1)

My vote for @chris85  which is most obvious and  performant.

Answer (score 1):

This one

```
^([\w]{3,8}-[\w]{3,8})$
```

https://regex101.com/r/uS8nB5/1